# Drawing Truth Tables? A && (B || D)

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm having trouble starting this truth table and drawing it out in my AP Computer Science class. A && (B || D) is what I have to draw.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a column for each individual value `(A, B, D)` and a row for every combination of values `2^3 = 8`. Then, have additional columns for each intermediate calculation. In the end have another column for the complete expression. Now you can do the calculations step by step.

You should end up with the following template:

```
 A | B | D | (B || D) | A && (B || D)
---+---+---+----------+--------------
 F | F | F |          |
 F | F | T |          |
 F | T | F |          |
 F | T | T |          |
 T | F | F |          |
 T | F | T |          |
 T | T | F |          |
 T | T | T |          |
```

From here on, you should be able to solve your task.

Answer (score 1):

Display all posibilities in first, and it will be easy ;)

```
+-----------+-----+
| A | B | C | Out |
|---|---|---|-----|
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  0  |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |  0  |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |  ?  |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |  ?  |
....
....
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  1  |
+-----------+-----+
```

I did the begin and the last for you ;)